# How to apply and remove class on click in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, onclick

How to apply and remove CSS classes on click of multiple div (which is rendered by array of items) in react?

```
<div 
  onClick={() => { setActiveDiv(`div${index}`) }}
  className={(activeDiv === `div${index}`) ? "activeFileName" : "inActiveFileName"}  
>
 {item?.name}
</div>
```

Comment: when does `inActiveFileName` class get applied? can u elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Is this code your you’ve tried? Assuming it uses Hooks? What’s not working, or what is the error?

Comment: You may want to be more explicit about your goal and your example. Maybe someone more familiar with React will understand based on the current information, but it seems unclear to me how to even begin to help you with it so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you want to add 'activeFileName' on div when it's clicked and remove it when another div is clicked.

For that, you need indexing while creating div.
Something like:

```
<div 
  data-index = {1}
  onClick={(evt) => { setActiveDiv(evt.target.getAttribute("data-index")}}
  className={(activeDiv === 1) ? "activeFileName" : "inActiveFileName"}  
>
  {item?.name}
</div>
<div 
  data-index = {2}
  onClick={(evt) => { setActiveDiv(evt.target.getAttribute("data-index")}}
  className={(activeDiv === 2) ? "activeFileName" : "inActiveFileName"}  
>
  {item?.name}
</div>
```

You can assign an index either dynamically using a map or some other logic.